# My program says identifier is expected

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, identifier

I'm trying to make a string binary search program. Trouble is I don't remember a straight forward way to convert  a string array into a Integer array.

I've written a long and complicated way to convert them. However Netsbeans is saying my string array identifier is expected.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


package javaapplication3;

/**
 *
 * @author Ivan Beazer
 */

import java.io.*;

/**
   This program demonstrates the search method in
   the IntBinarySearcher class.
*/
public class BinarySearchTest 
{
    private static String aString;
    // Convert string array to string
    public static String arrayToString2(String[] words, String aString) 
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        if (words.length > 0) 
        {
            result.append(words[0]);
            for (int i=1; i<words.length; i++) 
            {
                result.append(aString);
                result.append(words[i]);
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }    

   public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
   {
      int result, searchValue;
      String input;

      // A String array of words to search.
      // This is the error. netbeans says identifier is expected.
      String[] words = {"Jake", "Jerry". "Bill", "Lousie", "Goku", "Ivan", "John", "sarah", "kim"};

      // convert string to int array

      int[] numbers = new int[aString.length()];
      for(int i=0; i<aString.length(); i++)
        numbers[i] = Character.getNumericValue(aString.charAt(i));  

      // Create the console input objects.
      InputStreamReader reader =
                 new InputStreamReader(System.in);
      BufferedReader keyboard =
                 new BufferedReader(reader);

      // First we must sort the array in ascending order.
      IntQuickSorter.quickSort(numbers);

      do
      {
         // Get a value to search for.
         System.out.print("Enter a value to search for: ");
         input = keyboard.readLine();
         searchValue = Integer.parseInt(input);

         // Search for the value
         result = IntBinarySearcher.search(numbers, searchValue);

        // Display the results.
        if (result == -1)
           System.out.println(searchValue + " was not found.");
        else
        {
           System.out.println(searchValue + " was found at " +
                              "element " + result);
        }

        // Does the user want to search again?
        System.out.print("Do you want to search again? (Y or N): ");
        input = keyboard.readLine();
      } while (input.charAt(0) == 'y' || input.charAt(0) == 'Y');
   }
}

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package javaapplication3;

/**
 *
 * @author Devon B
 */
/**
   The IntBinarySearcher class provides a public static
   method for performing a binary search on an int array.
*/

public class IntBinarySearcher
{



   /**
      The search method performs a binary search on an int
      array. The array is searched for the number passed to
      value. If the number is found, its array subscript is
      returned. Otherwise, -1 is returned indicating the
      value was not found in the array.
      @param array The array to search.
      @param value The value to search for.
   */

   public static int search(int[] array, int value)
   {
      int first;       // First array element
      int last;        // Last array element
      int middle;      // Mid point of search
      int position;    // Position of search value
      boolean found;   // Flag

      // Set the inital values.
      first = 0;
      last = array.length - 1;
      position = -1;
      found = false;

      // Search for the value.
      while (!found && first <= last)
      {
         // Calculate mid point
         middle = (first + last) / 2;

         // If value is found at midpoint...
         if (array[middle] == value)
         {
            found = true;
            position = middle;
         }
         // else if value is in lower half...
         else if (array[middle] > value)
            last = middle - 1;
         // else if value is in upper half....
         else
            first = middle + 1;
      }

      // Return the position of the item, or -1
      // if it was not found.
      return position;


   }
}

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package javaapplication3;

/**
 *
 * @author Devon B
 */
/**
   The IntQuickSorter class provides a public static
   method for performing a QuickSort on an int array.
*/

public class IntQuickSorter
{
  /**
      The quickSort method calls the doQuickSort method
      to sort an int array.
      @param array The array to sort.
   */

   public static void quickSort(int array[])
   {
      doQuickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
   }

   /**
      The doQuickSort method uses the QuickSort algorithm
      to sort an int array.
      @param array The array to sort.
      @param start The starting subscript of the list to sort
      @param end The ending subscript of the list to sort
   */

   private static void doQuickSort(int array[], int start, int end)
   {
      int pivotPoint;

      if (start < end)
      {
         // Get the pivot point.
         pivotPoint = partition(array, start, end);

         // Sort the first sub list.
         doQuickSort(array, start, pivotPoint - 1);

         // Sort the second sub list.
         doQuickSort(array, pivotPoint + 1, end);
      }
   }

   /**
      The partiton method selects a pivot value in an array
      and arranges the array into two sub lists. All the
      values less than the pivot will be stored in the left
      sub list and all the values greater than or equal to
      the pivot will be stored in the right sub list.
      @param array The array to partition.
      @param start The starting subscript of the area to partition.
      @param end The ending subscript of the area to partition.
      @return The subscript of the pivot value.
   */

   private static int partition(int array[], int start, int end)
   {
      int pivotValue;    // To hold the pivot value
      int endOfLeftList; // Last element in the left sub list.
      int mid;           // To hold the mid-point subscript

      // Find the subscript of the middle element.
      // This will be our pivot value.
      mid = (start + end) / 2;

      // Swap the middle element with the first element.
      // This moves the pivot value to the start of
      // the list.
      swap(array, start, mid);

      // Save the pivot value for comparisons.
      pivotValue = array[start];

      // For now, the end of the left sub list is
      // the first element.
      endOfLeftList = start;

      // Scan the entire list and move any values that
      // are less than the pivot value to the left
      // sub list.
      for (int scan = start + 1; scan <= end; scan++)
      {
         if (array[scan] < pivotValue)
         {
            endOfLeftList++;
            swap(array, endOfLeftList, scan);
         }
      }

      // Move the pivot value to end of the
      // left sub list.
      swap(array, start, endOfLeftList);

      // Return the subscript of the pivot value.
      return endOfLeftList;
   }

   /**
      The swap method swaps the contents of two elements
      in an int array.
      @param The array containing the two elements.
      @param a The subscript of the first element.
      @param b The subscript of the second element.
   */

   private static void swap(int[] array, int a, int b)
   {
      int temp;

      temp = array[a];
      array[a] = array[b];
      array[b] = temp;
   }
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know an easier way to convert string array to string int.

Comment: Fixed it for you. Next time, simply select your code and press Ctrl+K to format it.

Comment: if you want a way to convert a string array to an integer array, you might want to ask a separate question for that. You don't need to include all your code. But search the site first because there's a pretty good chance someone has already asked that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look after the string `"Jerry"`:

```
String[] words = {"Jake", "Jerry". "Bill", "Lousie", "Goku", "Ivan", "John", "sarah", "kim"};
```

You have a dot ( . ) instead of a comma ( , )

Comment: Wow thanks, I should of gotten that. Thanks a lot Ken Wayne VanderLinde, this took me a hour to figure out.

Comment: Do you know a easier way to convert string array into integer array.

Comment: Could you expand on precisely what kind of conversion you are looking for?